# Questions about Hoare's partition scheme

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I struggle to implement Hoare's partition scheme as shown in the original article [here](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/366622.366642) (Algorithm 63):

> **ALGORITHM 63**
> **PARTITION**
> **C. A. R. Hoare**
> **Elliott Brothers Ltd., Borehamwood, Hertfordshire, Eng.**
>
> ```pascal
> procedure  partition (A,M,N,I,J);  value M,N; 
>             array A;  integer M,N,I,J;
> ```
>
> **comment** I and J are output variables, and A is the array (with
> subscript bounds M:N) which is operated upon by this procedure.
> Partition takes the value X of a random element of the array A,
> and rearranges the values of the elements of the array in such a
> way that there exist integers I and J with the following properties:
>
> ```
>                 M ≤ J < I ≤ N provided M < N 
>                 A[R] ≤ X for M ≤ R ≤ J 
>                 A[R] = X for J < R < I 
>                 A[R] ≥ X for I ≤ R ≤ N
> ```
>
> The procedure uses an integer procedure random (M,N) which
> chooses equiprobably a random integer F between M and N, and
> also a procedure exchange, which exchanges the values of its two
> parameters;
>
> ```pascal
> begin   real X;  integer F; 
>         F := random (M,N);  X := A[F]; 
>         I := M;  J := N; 
> up:     for I := I step 1 until N do 
>                    if X < A [I] then go to down; 
>         I := N; 
> down:   for J := J step -1 until M do 
>                    if A[J]<X then go to change; 
>         J := M; 
> change: if I < J then begin exchange (A[I], A[J]); 
>                             I := I + 1; J := J - 1; 
>                             go to up 
>                       end 
> else    if I < F then begin exchange (A[I], A[F]); 
>                             I := I + 1
>                       end 
> else    if F < J then begin exchange (A[F], A[J]); 
>                             J := J - 1 
>                       end; 
> end     partition
> ```

I don't understand some variable's initializations, i.e. `I:=N` and `J:=M`.

For the `up` part, there is:

```pascal
    for I := I step 1 until N do
                if X < A[I] then go to down;
    I := N
```

When is this supposed to occur? Since if it is outside of the loop it seems to always be skipped.

Later in the algorithm, there is:

```pascal
    if I < F then begin exchange (A[I], A[F]);
                        I := I + 1
                  end
```

As `exchange (A[I], A[F])` isn't on a new line, does it mean that A[I] and A[F] must be exchanged or that `I := I + 1` is supposed to exchange the values?

What is this algorithm supposed to return?

Comment: Seems to be a no-op, as the loop just before it ends on `I:=N` anyway. Possibly just there as a convenient reminder/comment (if you reach the end of this loop, I=...).

Comment: I'm not aware of conventions in algo articles so I wasn't sure. I thought there would be a sign to show comments. As it raised a new question, I'll update the question. Thank you.

Comment: "does exchange (A[I], A[F]); mean that A[I] and A[F] must be exchanged?" - yes. "is I := I + 1 supposed to exchange the values?" - no, what?

Comment: As ``exhange (A[I], A[F])`` wasn't on a new line, I thought it could be the name of a subroutine. I edited for more clarity.

Comment: The intro text says "uses procedure exchange, which..." `exchange` is assumed to exist, it is not part of this code. The procedure makes changes to A, I and J (M and N are marked as passed by value, so read only), that's its effect on the world (intro text: "I and J are output vars...").

Comment: If there is a new procedure, it will be marked by `procedure` keyword, it will not be introduced by ambush. If you want to know more about the notation, that was supposed to be [ALGOL 60](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL).

Comment: It did involve a random number. I found this article (published in July 1961) in one of the sources of your link. The implementation shown is based on CLRS which points to the same journal where can be found the original algorithm (which, unless proven otherwise, is the one I linked). @teapot418 if you post it as an answer, I will mark it as the right answer. Thank you for your time and for your help in both understand and the notation itself.

Comment: @Nocxy - I deleted my prior comment. Link to [Hoare's original scheme](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/6226/H2006%20-%20Historic%20Quicksort.pdf). This was a iterative implementation using an array as a stack, which Hoare calls it a "nest". Hoare  mentions using "sentinel" values to avoid having to do bounds check.  It's not clear if the concept of a "nest" or stack pre-dated Hoare's usage of it. Hoare later reimplemented it as a recursive algorithm using ALGOL. Later improvements changed the compares to < (instead of <=) and > (instead of >=) to avoid bounds check, but can exchange equal keys.

Comment: @Nocxy - another improvement was to choose the middle of a partition (segment) to handle the case of equal keys, already sorted keys, already reverse sorted keys.

Comment: I didn't understand how this was an improvement. Why does it handle these cases? This algorithm is still sorted as "unstable". Could you give me a link to an article talking about that?

Comment: @Nocxy - for equal keys, already sorted keys, or reverse sorted keys, choosing the middle element results in an optimal 50% / 50% split. The [wiki quicksort: choice of pivot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot) compares median of three to random pivot.

Comment: @Nocxy - [that same wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Using_percentiles) mentions that with a random pivot, the probability of a 25% / 75% split or better is about 50%, an average of a 12.5% | 87.5% split, versus middle element as pivot being 50% / 50% on equal keys, already sorted keys, reverse sorted keys.

Comment: I asked for an article i.e. a primary source. The link you point to doesn't refer to an article by Hoare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand some variable's initializations, i.e. I:=N and J:=M.

These are executed when the preceding loop finished all iterations without premature exit via the `go to` statement. I don't know whether all Algol60 compilers at the time would be consistent in which value the loop variable would have after finishing the loop, and this assignment just ensures that it is the "until" value of the loop range.

> Since if it is outside of the loop it seems to always be skipped.

They are only skipped if the `go to` was executed, but there can be cases where the loop finishes without this happening.

> As `exchange (A[I], A[F])` isn't on a new line, does it mean that `A[I]` and `A[F]` must be exchanged or that `I := I + 1` is supposed to exchange the values?

The layout of the code is confusing you. You can interpret it as follows:

```pascal
if I < F then
begin
    exchange (A[I], A[F]); 
    I := I + 1
end
```

> What is this algorithm supposed to return?

It is a procedure and so it doesn't have a return value. But the parameters `I` and `J` are called by reference, so the caller will get information back via those variables. Their significance is explained in the article:

> ```
>                 M ≤ J < I ≤ N provided M < N 
>                 A[R] ≤ X for M ≤ R ≤ J 
>                 A[R] = X for J < R < I 
>                 A[R] ≥ X for I ≤ R ≤ N
> ```

#### Implementation

As the presented code relies on call-by-reference, we could map it to C++. Here is an implementation, where I have stayed as close as possible to the original code (indentation, use of `goto` and labels, ...), completed with `quickSort` and driver code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int random(int low, int high) {
    return std::rand() % (high - low + 1) + low; 
}

void exchange(float &a, float &b) {
    float c = a;
    a = b;
    b = c;
}

void partition(float A[], int M, int N, int &I, int &J) {
begin:  float X; int F;
        F = random(M,N); X = A[F]; 
        I = M; J = N;
    
up:     for (I = I; I <= N; I += 1)
            if (X < A[I]) goto down;
        I = N;
    
down:   for (J = J; J >= M; J -= 1)
            if (A[J] < X) goto change; 
        J = M;
    
change: if (I < J) {  exchange(A[I], A[J]); 
                      I = I + 1; J = J - 1; 
                      goto up;
                   } 
   else if (I < F) {  exchange (A[I], A[F]); 
                      I = I + 1;
                   } 
   else if (F < J) {  exchange (A[F], A[J]); 
                      J = J - 1;
                   } 
}

void quickSort(float A[], int M, int N) {
    int I, J;
    if (M < N) {
        partition(A, M, N, I, J);
        quickSort(A, M, J);
        quickSort(A, I, N);
    }    
}

void printArr(float A[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << A[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    int size = 14;
    float A[] = {1, 5, 1, 9, 3, 4, 2, 8, 9, 4, 7, 7, 6, 8};
    std::srand(time(NULL));

    printArr(A, size); // Before sorting
    quickSort(A, 0, size - 1);
    printArr(A, size); // After sorting

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since the original commenter didn't post it as answer, I validate this one.