# Issue implementing Quicksort in c# with Hoare's partition scheme

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I can't implement [Hoare's partition scheme](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/366622.366642) in C#.

Here's the pseudocode for Hoare's partition scheme (as rewritten by trincot in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75995254/questions-about-hoares-partition-scheme)):

> **ALGORITHM 63**
> **PARTITION**
> **C. A. R. Hoare**
> **Elliott Brothers Ltd., Borehamwood, Hertfordshire, Eng.**
>
> ```pascal
> procedure  partition (A,M,N,I,J);  value M,N; 
>             array A;  integer M,N,I,J;
> ```
>
> **comment** I and J are output variables, and A is the array (with
> subscript bounds M:N) which is operated upon by this procedure.
> Partition takes the value X of a random element of the array A,
> and rearranges the values of the elements of the array in such a
> way that there exist integers I and J with the following properties:
>
> ```
>                 M ≤ J < I ≤ N provided M < N 
>                 A[R] ≤ X for M ≤ R ≤ J 
>                 A[R] = X for J < R < I 
>                 A[R] ≥ X for I ≤ R ≤ N
> ```
>
> The procedure uses an integer procedure random (M,N) which
> chooses equiprobably a random integer F between M and N, and
> also a procedure exchange, which exchanges the values of its two
> parameters;
>
> ```pascal
> begin   real X;  integer F; 
>         F := random (M,N);  X := A[F]; 
>         I := M;  J := N; 
> up:     for I := I step 1 until N do 
>                    if X < A [I] then go to down; 
>         I := N; 
> down:   for J := J step -1 until M do 
>                    if A[J]<X then go to change; 
>         J := M; 
> change: if I < J then begin exchange (A[I], A[J]); 
>                             I := I + 1; J := J - 1; 
>                             go to up 
>                       end 
> else    if I < F then begin exchange (A[I], A[F]); 
>                             I := I + 1
>                       end 
> else    if F < J then begin exchange (A[F], A[J]); 
>                             J := J - 1 
>                       end; 
> end     partition
> ```

I ended up with this:

```cs
class QuicksortImplementation
{

    public static int[] Partition(int[] a) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int f = random.Next(0, a.Length);
        int x = a[f];
        int i = 0;
        int j = a.Length - 1;
        while (true) {
            while (i < a.Length) {
                if (x < a[i]) {
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
            while (j > 0) {
                if (a[j] < x) {
                    break;
                }
                j--;
            }
            if (i < j) {
                (a[i], a[j]) = (a[j], a[i]);
                i = i + 1;
                j = j - 1;
                continue;
            }
            else if (i < f) {
                (a[i], a[f]) = (a[f], a[i]);
                i = i + 1;
                break;
            }
            else if (f < j) {
                (a[f], a[j]) = (a[j], a[f]);
                j = j - 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        return new[] { i, j };
    }

    public static int[] Quicksort(int[] a, int low, int high) {
        if (low < high) {
            int[] return_array = Partition(a);
            int i = return_array[0];
            int j = return_array[1];
            low = 0;
            high = a.Length;
            Quicksort(a, low, j);
            Quicksort(a, i, high);
        }
        return a;
    }

    static void Main() {
        int[] a = { 51, 1, 3, 4, 98 };
        int[] new_a = new int[a.Length];
        new_a = Quicksort(a, 0, a.Length);
        System.Console.WriteLine(new_a.ToString());
    }
}
```

I always end up in an infinite loop.

What should I change to make it work?

Comment: Do you think *infinite loop* different from *unterminating recursion*? How did you establish *infinite loop*? The process to investigate program behaviour you don't approve of is debugging: What tools are you going to use, what procedures?

Comment: I meant it never hits a ``break`` in the outer loop. I use VScode's debugger and at some point no variable changes, resulting in the program never terminating.

Comment: `at some point no variable changes, [the program never terminates]` So what "*does* the program do" in this state?

Comment: By setting `low = 0` and `high = a.Length` you have indeed caused the recursion to never hit the base case (which requires that `low >= high`). Also the `Partition` function needs a range too. Look at the parameters in the pseudo code...

Comment: The comment states that M and N are the subscript bounds of A so I replaced M by ``0`` and N by ``a.Length`` in ``Partition`` and ``Quicksort``.

Comment: Observe some variables using "print statements", or means of the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

There are the following issues:

- Your code resets `low` and `high` to 0 and `a.Length` respectively. This should not happen: the bounds of the array are supposed to get *smaller* as the recursion deepens. By this reset, the recursion will never stop.
- The pseudo code will stop looping when `i >= j`, even when the two next conditions concerning `f` are not true. In your code the loop only exits when one of those two `f` conditions are true. This can be a cause for an infinite loop. It is more natural to perform these two `f` related conditions *after* having exited the loop.
- The pseudo code has `M` and `N` as **input** parameters for the `partition` function, but in your code, there are no such inputs, which means the `Partition` function looks at the *whole* array every time it runs. Instead it is supposed to look at the subarray that is bounded by `M` and `N` (`low` and `high` in your code).
- On the one hand you pass a value for `high` that is an index that is *excluded* from the range (the last index in the range is `high-1`), but on the other hand you call the function recursively with `j` for the `high` parameter: but that is an index that should be considered part of the partition. The pseudo code uses `M:N` bounds where `N` is *inclusive*. This means your `high` argument should start out with the value `a.Length-1` instead of `a.Length`.
- The main program should not allocate a new array: the sort will happen *inplace*, and for that reason the `quickSort` function should better not return the array either (to not confuse the caller). It will be the input array that is mutated.

Here is a corrected version:

```
using System;

class Program {
    public static int[] Partition(int[] a, int low, int high) { // Parameters!
        Random random = new Random();
        int f = random.Next(low, high + 1); // Adjusted, since high is inclusive 
        int x = a[f];
        int i = low; // Use low
        int j = high; // Adjusted, since high is inclusive now
        while (true) {
            while (i < high) { // use high
                if (x < a[i]) {
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
            while (j > low) {  // use low
                if (a[j] < x) {
                    break;
                }
                j--;
            }
            if (i >= j) break; // This condition alone is enough to exit
            (a[i], a[j]) = (a[j], a[i]);
            i = i + 1;
            j = j - 1;
        }
        // Do this only once, after the loop
        if (i < f) {
            (a[i], a[f]) = (a[f], a[i]);
            i = i + 1;
        }
        else if (f < j) {
            (a[f], a[j]) = (a[j], a[f]);
            j = j - 1;
        }
        return new[] { i, j };
    }

    public static void Quicksort(int[] a, int low, int high) { // No return value
        if (low < high) {
            int[] return_array = Partition(a, low, high); // pass the range!
            int i = return_array[0];
            int j = return_array[1];
            // Don't reset low, high here!
            Quicksort(a, low, j);
            Quicksort(a, i, high);
        }
    }
    
    static void Main() {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++) {
            int[] a = { 5, 1, 8, 3, 4, 9, 6, 2, 0, 7 };
            // No new array to be allocated -- sort is inplace
            Quicksort(a, 0, a.Length - 1); // high argument adapted
            System.Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", a)); // print
        }
    }
}
```